# DB-agnostic Calculations : Is it good to store calculation results ? If yes, what's the better way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, callback

I want to perform some simple calculations while staying database-agnostic in my rails app.

I have three models:

```
 .---------------.       .--------------.           .---------------.
 | ImpactSummary |<------| ImpactReport |<----------| ImpactAuction |
 `---------------'1     *`--------------'1         *`---------------'
```

Basicly:

- `ImpactAuction` holds data about... auctions (prices, quantities and such).
- `ImpactReport` holds monthly reports that have many auctions as well as other attributes ; it also shows some calculation results based on the auctions.
- `ImpactSummary` holds a collection of reports as well as some information about a specific year, and also shows calculation results based on the two other models.

What i intend to do is to store the results of these really simple calculations (just means, sums, and the like) in the relevant tables, so that reading these would be fast, and in a way that i can easilly perform queries on the calculation results.

1. **is it good practice to store calculation results ?** I'm pretty sure that's not a very good thing, but is it acceptable ?
2. **is it useful, or should i not bother and perform the calculations on-the-fly?**
3. **if it is good practice and useful, what's the better way to achieve what i want ?**

Thats the tricky part.*At first, i implemented a simple chain of callbacks* that would update the calculation fields of the parent model upon save (that is, when an auction is created or updated, it marks `some_attribute_will_change!` on its report and saves it, which triggers its own callbacks, and so on).

This approach fits well when creating / updating a single record, but if i want to work on several records, it will trigger the calculations on the whole chain for each record... So i suddenly find myself forced to put a condition on the callbacks... depending on if i have one or many records, which i can't figure out how (using a class method that could be called on a relation? using an instance attribute `@skip_calculations` on each record? just using an `outdated` field to mark the parent records for later calculation ?).

Any advice is welcome.

**Bonus question:** Would it be considered DB agnostic if i implement this with DB views ?

Comment: storing seems overkill but caching could suit

Comment: yes, i thought about this. i'm not really familiar with caching, do you know good "noob doc" about this ? moreover, it wont help me querying the results in a db-agnostic way... what happens if i need to select the summaries on calculations criteria ?

Comment: ok, i'll try this. Just to keep on learning :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it depends. If you can perform the calculations in the database, either using a view or using `#find_by_sql`, I would do so. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble: you have to keep your summaries up to date when you change values. You've already met the problem when updating multiple rows. Having a view, or a query that implements the view stored as text in ImpactReport, will allow you to always have fresh data.

The answer? Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark ;)

Comment: following @apneadiving's advice, i'm trying this using cached on-the-fly calculations along with `includes` queries to limit db load. I already implemented similar logic using complex sql queries, but it just doesn't feel "rails way"... we'll see what the benchmark says !
Thanks for your time.